# How do I test a field in a struct that is a reference

Tags: c++, googletest

With googletest, how can I test the value of struct that is a reference-type?

Given the following struct:

```
struct Thing {
    const std::string& a;
    const std::string& b;
};
```

Now I want to test the value for one of the members in a callback.

```
TEST(Test, test1)
{
    testing::StrictMock<testing::MockFunction<void(const Thing &)>> callback;
    Thing t {"aaa", "bbb"}; // Note, this is simplified, in the real world I do not have direct access to t.
    
    {
        EXPECT_CALL(callback, Call(testing::Field(&Thing::b, testing::Eq("bbb"))));
        callback.AsStdFunction()(t);
    }
}
```

However, this does not compile: `error: cannot create pointer to reference member 'Thing::b'`

If I make the members of the `Thing` struct non-references the problem goes away, however I cannot do that in my situation. In my test I only want to check for one field.

Full example: https://godbolt.org/z/9cb5MoMP9

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you have get/set in `Thing` try to check `Property` instead of `Field`. Good example where you expect `const T&` to be `T` but it's not. The problem is that reference `a` stored at address `x` is an alias to some variable `i` at some memory `y`. So if you point to `x` of reference `a` it's not the address `y` of variable `i` as you want.